# Kernel missing 'arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel.ko'

Tags: git, ubuntu, linux-kernel, driver, arch

I am trying to compile and install a Linux Kernel on Ubuntu, and I keep running into the same error, when trying to run

```
make modules_install install
```

The error reads

```bash
cp cannot stat 'arch/x86/crypto/aesni-intel.ko' No such file or directory
```

I have tried multiple solutions to no avail. I am on Ubuntu 20.04.6

The series of steps I took to arrive here are shown below, all without error except for that part

```bash
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git linux_stable
cd linux_stable
git branch -a | grep linux-5
    remotes/origin/linux-5.12.y
    remotes/origin/linux-5.11.y
    remotes/origin/linux-5.10.y

​git checkout linux-5.12.

ls /boot
config-5.0.0-20-generic        memtest86+.bin
config-5.0.0-21-generic        memtest86+.elf
efi                            memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                           System.map-5.0.0-20-generic
initrd.img-5.0.0-20-generic    System.map-5.0.0-21-generic
initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic    vmlinuz-5.0.0-20-generic
lost+found                     vmlinuz-5.0.0-21-generic

cp /boot/<config-5.0.0-21-generic> .config

make oldconfig

make -j3 all

make modules_install install
```

The last command is the one giving me all these issues. I have tried different version of ubuntu, different kernels, and this is all where they fail with the exact same error

Comment: Did it build when you ran `make modules`?

Comment: Yeah it ran when I used that command, and I also saw the modules it created when I ran it, the only problem is that command when I try to install it